# MySQL - Database design - separate tables for users and profile

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

From what I've been reading online, I understood that it's better to split the data into more tables, if possible because of the access times.

Right now I have a table in which I am storing usernames, passwords and join date
This is how my table looks:

```
'user'
'user_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_username VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
user_password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
user_join_date INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id) ');
```

I am trying to create a new table called profiles in which I want to store first name, last name, email, age and gender. What I think is that I need a one-to-one relationship, so I should be using the user_id but I'm not really sure how to implement it.

Should I create another table called profiles with 
profiles

```
profiles_id
first_name
last_name
email
age 
gender
```

and another one which should be the relationship ? e.g.

```
user_profiles
----------
user_id
profiles_id
```

Is this right? How would the SQL look for the user_profiles?

Thanks

Comment: . . Your first statement is incorrect.  Can you reference what you've been reading online?  Sometimes using multiple tables is better, sometimes not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, you create an *association table*, like `user_profiles` you have described when one user could have more than one profile, and/or one profile could belong to one or more user.

As you have said, here you have a `one-to-one` relationship between `user` and `profile`. So, you can simply add a `user_id` column to your `profile` table, and define it as a foreign key to `user` table.

Then, a simple `JOIN` will allow you to query both tables at the same time:

```
SELECT u.*, p.*
FROM user u
JOIN profile p ON u.user_id = p.user_id
```

Comment: I am confused by the comments on stack overflow. I made a new table called profiles which has: profiles_id, user_id, first_name... primary key(profiles_id) and foreign key(user_id) that references to the user table. Now, if I am adding data into a form, when should I run that query? Or actually, what is it doing? Is it setting some sort of relationship between tables? Sorry for being so confused

Comment: It is indeed creating a relationship between tables, but inserting and retrieving data should take this schema into account. You should first `INSERT INTO user (...) VALUES (...)`, then retrieve [the last inserted id](http://php.net/manual/pdo.lastinsertid.php) and `INSERT INTO profile(user_id, ...) VALUES ($last_id, ...)` with the reference to the user.

Comment: Ok, I did that, but i figured out that the last inserted id only works if i ask for it after the Insert. But I have a file for the insert into user, and another file for the insert into profile. What could I do to retrieve the last_id so I can have it in the other file, in which I'm inserting into profiles? (I don't really use PDO, so I used mysql_insert_id)

Comment: gives me this error Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`projectdb`.`profiles`, CONSTRAINT `tb_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`))

Answer (score 9):

Don't split the tables. Just add the new columns to your existing `user` table. You might find later on that splitting tables is a good idea based on actual queries and usage patterns but until you have that kind of data, keep things simple.

If you must create a profile table, don't create a `user_profiles` table. That would allow an m-to-n relationship which is probably not what you want. A simple `user_id` column in `profiles` is better. In fact, it could be both a foreign key and the primary key to make sure that each `user` row only have one and only one `profile` row (although by splitting the tables you might still have a user with no profile).

Comment: I like this approach because it avoids a JOIN each time you want to query a User's information. However, I wonder how good this is in terms of database normalization rules. Any comments on that?

Answer (score 2):

Add a new field in the User table, ProfileId, and set it as Foreign Key (FK). Each time you create a User, you have to assign to it a profile (which will be the ProfileId PK from profile table).
If you want to see also the profile information of a user, you have to do a join

```
Select username, first_name,second_name
From user u, profile p
Where u.profileId = p.profileId
```

this

```
user_profiles
----------
user_id
profiles_id
```

is used in a many-to-many relationship. By example, you want to assign to an admin some privileges, but those privileges can be also assigned to more admins. Then, you have to create a 3rd table to solve this problem. Here is an example, but you don't need to do this. [image]

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `user_id` field to your profiles table and `JOIN` the tables on `user_id`.

```
SELECT user.user_username, ..., profiles.first_name, ...
FROM user
INNER JOIN profiles
ON user.user_id = profiles.user_id
```

This should fetch data combining information from those rows where the JOIN condition is met (i.e. `user.user_id = profiles.user_id`).

Answer (score 1):

It is true that having more than one tables is a good idea. I am not sure what you mean about access time, but there are other advantages.
- Your users database containing passwords etc is "sacred", you never change its structure and you limit the rights to it (read, write) to the strict minimum.
- You can then have several "satelites" tables such as profiles, private messages, etc which are more flexible, less sensitive and which you can change all the time.

About your question per se, there is no need for a separate table with the relationships. In fact is a very bad idea which will complicate your queries and doesn't have any advantage. Instead, in your profiles database you will have one column that refers back to the user id.

```
users
--------
id
user_name
email
password


users_profiles
---------
id
user_id
favourite_animal
```

Answer (score 0):

Table `user`

```
user_id |user_username |user_password |user_join_date |profile_id
```

Table `profile`

```
profile_id |first name |last name |email |age |gender
```

When selecting a user by user id:

```
SELECT u.*, p.* FROM user AS u INNER JOIN  `profile` AS p ON u.profile_id = p.profile_id WHERE u.user_id = 1
```

But a user should only one gender, one age, one name and surname. Maybe e-mail adresses might be many. I suggest you there is no need to join tables which have a 1-to-1 relation. Instead merge those tables.